# insert text in the middle of string in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex

can you please help me with this issue the String class does not have insert method it has only replace :( .

what I need is:
- if I have string "I stackoverflow" 
- I need to insert "love " at index 2 to have "I love stackoverflow"

so what I need is **insertAt(index, String)**

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build one of your own. Split the string and concatenate all characters before the `index` position with the characters of the string you want to insert and with the characters after the `index`.

eg:

```
String s = "I stackoverflow";
int index = s.indexOf(" ");
String toInsert = "love ";
String mys = s.substring(0, index) + toInsert + s.substring(index, s.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

`var s:String = "I StackOverflow";
var t:String = s.split(" ").join(" love ");`